# php mysql shuffle output speed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query that returns 20 results from a table of 110,000,000.  I would like to shuffle these before echoing them out using php.

Is it faster to use

```
ORDER RAND()
```

or

shuffle the array in php somehow?

Comment: Try it and see: http://php.net/microtime#example-629

Comment: Do you want to shuffle all 11 million results and select 20 random results from the set of 11 million, or do you want to pick a predictable set of 20 results, and then shuffle those?

Comment: @Frank: pick a predictable 20 then shuffle them.

Comment: I'd just shuffle those in PHP then.  The worst-case performance for ORDER BY RAND() is very bad, as many google search results will reflect: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22order+by+rand%22 .  I expect you *could* come up with a reasonable ORDER BY RAND in this situation, but I wouldn't bother -- it's just as easy to `shuffle()` in PHP in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the amount of results you're pulling back from MySQL, `ORDER BY RAND()` will be faster.

If you're only returning 20 like you say, the performance differences will be negligible.

You could always test it out and see which is better for you, to shuffle an array in PHP you would use `shuffle()`.